# wp_post not working, keeps redirecting to posts page

Tags: plugins, wp-admin

I've been on this for more than two weeks, I've looked up a lot resources, I keep getting the same results; my site redirecting to posts page without executing anything in the defined function.
I'm trying to get the value of $_POST data with admin_post hook. Below is the hook and the function

```
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_add_foobar', 'prefix_admin_add_foobar' );
function prefix_admin_add_foobar() {
    status_header(200);
    $mydata = $_POST['data'];
    echo '<script>
        console.log('.$mydata.');
    </script>';
    //request handlers should exit() when they complete their task
    wp_redirect('somewhereelse.php');
    exit();
}
```

and below is the form

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url('admin-post.php') ); ?>" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_foobar">
   <input type="hidden" name="data" value="foobarid">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I'm testing this on wamp localhost, I don't know if it might be a factor.
I'm also not sure if I should add the hook and its function in function.php or inside the page template file.

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to run JS code, using WordPress `post` action handler will not give you the solution.

You will need to use ajax for that.

I have created a small example you can copy/paste.

```html
<form method="post" class="myform">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_foobar">
    <input type="hidden" name="data" value="foobarid">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

For our form I removed the action (no need for it because we will use ajax).
Also added a class for easier targeting.

```js
($ => {
    $('.myform').on('submit', e => {
        // prevent form from submit
        e.preventDefault();

        // get current element (form)
        const $this = $(e.currentTarget);

        // get form values
        const action = $this.find('[name="action"]').val();
        const data   = $this.find('[name="data"]').val();
    
        // send the form data to our ajax action,
        // and handle the response
        // btSystemGlobals.ajaxUrl = http://localhost/timber/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
        // I have a property that contains the ajax endpoint
        // you can copy the url but change it accordingly
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            url: btSystemGlobals.ajaxUrl, // btSystemGlobals.ajaxUrl = http://localhost/timber/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
            data: {
                action,
                data
            },
            success: res => {
                if (res.status) location.href = res.redirectTo;
                else console.log(res);
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

The JS that will handle the request/response.
I used ajax to keep it simple but you can use axios for a modern approach, plus it will make the code much shorter and easier to read (I could add it if thats something you want).

```php
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_add_foobar', 'add_foobar');
function add_foobar () {
    // get and sanitize the passed data
    $data = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'data', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    // do what ever logic you need here with $data

    // create the response
    $res = [
        'status'     => true,
        'data'       => $data,
        'redirectTo' => 'http://example.com/'
    ];

    // return the response as json object
    echo json_encode($res);
    // die, stop any other code from running after this point
    die;
}
```

And finally our action that will handle the data and return a response.
I didn't use **nonce** to keep it as simple as possible but consider adding it (also something I can add if you want).

Using the code you provided I created this short example for handling JS code with ajax and a form.
If you ever need to run JS code for form submission and PHP logic you will need to use a XHR request, so ajax/axios/fetch would be the correct approach.

Comment: My intention was not to run a Js code, I was only trying to log something and see if it works but it doesn't. Your approach is good and I might later settle for it. I'm trying to use this as a meta box extension for homepage design where admin can add some information. I want everything to Flow naturally such that when a page set as the home page is updated, the additional information can be submitted, processed and stored in the database.

Comment: @Stephynoe If thats the case then the problem is `admin_post_nopriv_add_foobar`, this action handles requests from not logged in users, but you are logged in, you will need to use `admin_post_add_foobar`

Comment: I've done that several times, but it won't hurt to try again. Thanks for your response.